# error when looping through multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a function to loop through multidimensional array :

```
function in_multiarray($elem, $array, $field)
{
    $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
    $bottom = 0;
    while($bottom <= $top)
    {
      if($array[$bottom][$field] == $elem)
        return true;
      else 
        if(is_array($array[$bottom][$field]))
            if(in_multiarray($elem, ($array[$bottom][$field])))
                return true;
      $bottom++;
    }        
   return false;

}
```

Then, I use it like this :

```
$hoursoff = array( array("10:00" => "2016-10-07", "11:00" => "2016-10-07", "12:00" => "2016-10-07"), array("10:00" => "2016-10-08", "11:00" => "2016-10-08") );

if( in_multiarray("$date", $hoursoff, "$hour") ) { /* do it */ } else { /* don't do it */ }
 /* $date and $hour come from database request */
```

this works fine. But when I check my error_reporting(E_ALL); it throws

```
 Notice: Undefined index ...
```

I know it's no big deal, and does not affect results, but in order to learn from this :
* which part of the script is involved in this error ?
* how do I avoid having this (or what am I doing wrong) ?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: What is the value of `$date` and `$hour`?

Comment: @RaxWeber : $date and $hour come from database request : I echo them and use them

Comment: Please post the full **Notice**

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: 9:00 or Notice: Undefined index: 14:00 and so on... one for each hour that is not in the array $hoursoff

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop instead of while loop as you could work with index of your array first

Then you're checking if `$date` exist there is no key in your array and key starting with `$` is not a right index ; in your 2nd dimension index are "10:00" , "11:00" and not `date` or `hour`

Answer (score 0):

I would also test for `isset($array[$bottom])` and `isset($array[$bottom][$field])` in all `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

If your multidimensionnal array doesn't have the same structure for every elements you might want to add some `isset()` functions to test if the array with its associated key exists before you do a test on it inside an `if()` statement.